# Struggling to insert values correctly into database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, mysqli

I want use a multi-dimensional array in this format: value[n][], where n is the question number. With this new setup, you should end up with the following input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" value="A" name="value[1][]">
<input type="hidden" value="B" name="value[1][]">
<input type="hidden" value="A" name="value[2][]">
<input type="hidden" value="C" name="value[2][]">
<input type="hidden" value="E" name="value[2][]">
```

Note that the selected value is encoded in the value attribute. The name attribute only contains the question to which the value belongs.

So what the above inputs are stating is this:

```
question 1: answer: A
question 1: answer: B
question 2: answer: A
question 2: answer: C
question 2: answer: E
```

I want to insert these details into "Question" and "Answer" database tables below:

Question Table:

```
SessionId    QuestionId

MUL             1
MUL             2
```

Answer Table:

```
 AnswerId (auto)  SessionId  QuestionId   Answer
 1                MUL        1            A
 2                MUL        1            B
 3                MUL        2            A
 4                MUL        2            C
 5                MUL        2            E
```

Now I have attempted writing the mysqli/php code below to insert these values into the database but I am receiving errors and failing badly in wanting to acheive what I want to achieve. I need help being able to correctly insert the correct values in the relevant tables.

Below is the php/mysqli code:

```
var_dump($_POST);  

$i = 0;
$c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){

/*
    switch ($_POST['gridValues'][$i]){

    case "3": 
    $selected_option = "A-C";
    break;

    case "4": 
    $selected_option = "A-D";
    break;

    case "5": 
    $selected_option = "A-E";
    break;

    default:
    $selected_option = "";
    break;

    }   

    */ needed later on when I insert grid values   



$results = $_POST['value'];
foreach($results as $id => $value) {
$answer = implode(':', $value);

 $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";

    $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');


    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

$insert->bind_param("si", $sessid, $id);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();

        $lastID = $id->insert_id;

        foreach($value as $answer) {

         $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (SessionId, QuestionId, Answer) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";

      if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }  

    $insertanswer->bind_param("sis" $sessid, $lastID, $answer);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insertanswer->close();


}

}

}
```

The `var_dump($_POST)` outputs this below:

```
array(3) {
["numQuestion"]=> array(2) { 
  [0]=> string(1) "1" 
  [1]=> string(1) "2" }
["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details"
["value"]=> array(4) { 
  ["answerARow"]=> string(1) "A" 
  ["answerCRow"]=> string(1) "C" 
  ["answerBRow"]=> string(1) "B" 
  ["answerERow"]=> string(1) "E" }
}
```

Below are the errors I am receiving and the line of code each error is linked to:

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /.../ on line 226

```
$answer = implode(':', $value);
```

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../ on line 250

```
$lastID = $id->insert_id;
```

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /.../ on line 252

```
foreach($value as $answer) {
```

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (23000/1062): Duplicate entry
>   'MUL-0' for key 'PRIMARY' in /.../ on line 242

The Above Error Points to the `$insert` query

MORE INFO:

The structure I really want to acheive after posting the text inputs is below:

```
array(2) { 
            ["numQuestion"]=> array(2) { 
                                        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
                                        [1]=> string(1) "2" 
                                       }
           ["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details" 
           ["1"] => array(2) {
                                        [0] => string(1) "A"
                                        [1] => string(1) "C"
                                      }
           ["2"] => array(2) {
                                        [0] => string(1) "A"
                                        [1] => string(1) "B"
                                        [2] => string(1) "E"
                                      }
        }
```

When the user posts the text input values, it should insert the question numbers and the answers which belongs to their relevant question number.

Comment: In non-technical terms, what are you trying to do overall? Like what's the highest-level big picture, and which part are you trying to tackle right now? I ask because I suspect you might benefit from a fundamentally different approach.

Comment: @JasonSwett I included an update in my question on the structure I want to acheive after posting the inputs

Comment: I meant way more high-level than that. Is this an app to help high school teachers keep track of grades? What does the app do?

Comment: Its an app where a teacher creates questions and answers for an exam. There can be single or multiple answer for a question

Comment: Okay, thanks. Why are you propagating answer values through hidden fields on a form?

Comment: The layout of each question is done a in a table row. Row 1 is question 1, row 2 is question 2 etc. The teacher selects an option type for a question, lets say the selects option type "A-E", then buttons A.B,C,D and E appears. Now the answers to each question depends on which buttons are turned on. For question 1, if buttons A and C are turned on, then their hidden input fields will appear showing the answer values of the turned on buttons for that question, it is them hidden input fields we $_POST and Insert into the database for each question

Comment: Okay. Since you already know the answer to each question, I think it might make sense to have a field for each question called `number_of_answers_turned_on` or something. 2 would mean just A and B, 4 would mean A, B, C, D, etc. This would probably make your form and `$_POST` a lot simpler.

Comment: @JasonSwett I have a jsfiddle here you can look at to what my app looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/58/

Please follow steps in fiddle:

1: When you open fiddle, click on "Add Question" button twice, this will append 2 rows.

2: In first row select answer buttons "A" and "C", in second row select answer buttons "A", "B" and "E". The text input values for each answer button selected is displayed underneath.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. My idea doesn't make sense, then. What I would probably do in this case is hidden checkboxes rather than `input type="hidden"` fields.

Comment: @JasonSwett Is there a lot of changes that needs to be done in the code? Im worried that because I am too deep into my code that it will take too much time to change hidden inputs into checkboxes. Or is it simply just changing the html hidden input into html checkbox and then hide them. Im just worried a lot of changes are need in the jquery code?

Comment: I have no idea, but I'm guessing probably yes. If I were you, I would pretty much just start over. Get something really small and simple 100% working, then add a little, get that 100% working, and keep going little by little. This approach would probably be faster than debugging what you have now.

Comment: Ok is it ok if can ask you a favor then ,if I change it to hidden checkboxes, what will the php/mysqli code then look like for when it comes to inserting question numbers and answer into the database? I will try and get hidden checkboxes working :)

Comment: Maybe you could get started with that, then ask a separate question (and I'll be happy to help). Start small! Maybe just start with one single question.

Comment: Ok, what I will do is obviously get started on changing from hidden input to checkboxes, then I will send a link to a seperate question for you when it comes to dealing with the php/mysqli code. Hopefully I can figure out the checkbox thing asap so then I can post the separate question later on today :)

Comment: Here is link to separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866313/how-to-post-and-insert-values-into-the-database-correctly. I have managed to change it to hidden checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. `$result` / `$_POST['value']` is a one-dimensional array, so `$value` in your `foreach`
   loop is a string that you cannot use `implode` on;
2. `$lastID = $id->insert_id;` should be `$insert->insert_id` and I'm not sure if you can close the connection already before you call
   that statement;
3. `$value` is a string (see first point) so you cannot use `foreach` there (third warning).

Comment: Problem 2 has been fixed but need help on problem 1 and 3. For problem 1 should it be `$_POST['value'][$i]`?

Comment: @user1701484 I don't know what you expect the result of the `implode` to be, you should clarify that in your question. Note that in your tables you don't have any strings like `A:B:C`.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I forgot and changed my mind and I didn't want to display it as A:B:C so you are right, I don't need the implode. So should the line now be: `$answer = $value;`

Comment: I updated code and I included another error I am receiving which shows that it is not inserting the question numbers into the database because I am getting duplicate rows inserted. Check the bottom error.