# How to post and insert values into the database correctly?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I want use a multi-dimensional array in this format: value[n][], where n is the question number. With this new setup, you should end up with the following checkbox fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="A" name="value[1][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="B" name="value[1][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="A" name="value[2][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="C" name="value[2][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="E" name="value[2][]">
```

Note that the selected value is encoded in the value attribute. The name attribute only contains the question to which the value belongs.

So what the above inputs are stating is this:

```
question 1: answer: A
question 1: answer: B
question 2: answer: A
question 2: answer: C
question 2: answer: E
```

I want to insert these details into "Question" and "Answer" database tables below:

Question Table:

```
SessionId    QuestionId

MUL             1
MUL             2
```

Answer Table:

```
 AnswerId (auto)  SessionId  QuestionId   Answer
 1                MUL        1            A
 2                MUL        1            B
 3                MUL        2            A
 4                MUL        2            C
 5                MUL        2            E
```

Now I have attempted writing the mysqli/php code below to insert these values into the database but I am receiving errors and failing badly in wanting to acheive what I want to achieve. I need help being able to correctly insert the correct values in the relevant tables.

Below is the php/mysqli code:

```
var_dump($_POST);  

$i = 0;
$c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){

/*
    switch ($_POST['gridValues'][$i]){

    case "3": 
    $selected_option = "A-C";
    break;

    case "4": 
    $selected_option = "A-D";
    break;

    case "5": 
    $selected_option = "A-E";
    break;

    default:
    $selected_option = "";
    break;

    }   

    */ needed later on when I insert grid values   



$results = $_POST['value'];
foreach($results as $id => $value) {
$answer = $value;

 $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId) 
    VALUES (?, ?)";

    $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');


    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

$insert->bind_param("si", $sessid, $id);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();

        $insert->insert_id;

        foreach($value as $answer) {

         $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (SessionId, QuestionId, Answer) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

      if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }  

    $insertanswer->bind_param("sis" $sessid, $lastID, $answer);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insertanswer->close();


}

}

}
```

The `var_dump($_POST)` outputs this below:

```
    array(3) { 
["numQuestion"]=> array(2) { 
[0]=> string(1) "1" 
[1]=> string(1) "2" 
}  
["submitDetails"]=> string(14) "Submit Details" ["value"]=> array(4) { 
["answerARow"]=> string(2) "on" 
["answerCRow"]=> string(2) "on" 
["answerBRow"]=> string(2) "on" ["answerERow"]=> string(2) "on"
 } 
}
```

Below are the errors I am receiving and the line of code each error is linked to:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /.../ on line 252

```
foreach($value as $answer) {
```

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (23000/1062): Duplicate entry
>   'MUL-0' for key 'PRIMARY' in /.../ on line 242

The above error shows that no question number is being inserted as it keeps displaying it as '0'

Comment: You are doing an outer foreach that loops through `$_POST['value']` and assigns the keys to `$id` and the values to `$value`. So the `$id`s are "answerARow", "answerCRow", etc and the `$value`s are "A", "C", "B", and "E". Obviously you can't loop over a string, hence the foreach error.

Comment: Your $_POST isn't matching your form?  where do the `answerARow` type keys come from/

Comment: @ernie The answerARow comes from answer buttons the user selects:   I have a jsfiddle here you can look at to what my app looks like: jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/59 Please follow steps in fiddle: 1: When you open fiddle, click on "Add Question" button twice, this will append 2 rows. 2: In first row select answer buttons "A" and "C", in second row select answer buttons "A", "B" and "E". The text input values for each answer button selected is displayed underneath.

Comment: that link doesn't work . . . the issue is that your input form is not submitting data in an array like you're expecting.  Fix the form, and then your code should work fine.

Comment: Looks like there is no revision 59 in your jsFiddle. This link works: http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/58/

Comment: Updated fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ybZvv/61/

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the main thing you're trying to do is to get around the inability to skin checkboxes. I have done this before. The way I did it was with using a span tied to a hidden checkbox.

I used spans because I'm not sure if a button in a form field will post a value when the form is submitted. I know that a span will not. This guarantees that only your checkbox value will be submitted, and not the "cover-up" value.

In your jsFiddle, in the `updateAnswer()` function, you have this code:

```
if (!bDisableAppend) {
    // append those values to the form
    var input = '<input type="checkbox" id="' + hid + '" name="value[' + id + ']" checked /><label for="' + hid + '">' + value + '</label>';
    _oCurrAnswerContainer.append(input);
}
```

In that code, you are setting the `name` attribute of the checkbox to something like `value[answerARow]`. That is where your problem is.

TBH, it's kinda hard for me to follow your code, so the solution I came up with will probably need some tweaking to add whatever kind of hidden trickery I missed in your example. But here is what I came up with:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eg5QU/3/)**

**JS/jQuery:**

```
var options = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"];


// this will bind the event handler to the document element, so that even when a new element is created,
// the event will be automatically bound to it.
$(document).on("click", "span.checkbox", function() {
    $("#chk"+ $(this).attr("id")).click();
    $(this).toggleClass("unselected selected");
});


$("#btnAddQuestion").click(function() {
    var questionNum = $("#tblQuestions tbody tr").length+1;

    var cell = $(document.createElement("td")).addClass("optAns").html("Answer:<br />");

    // loop through the options and add them to the cell
    for (var i in options)    
    {
        $(cell).append(
            // the front-end overlay for the checkbox
            $(document.createElement("span"))
                .addClass("checkbox unselected")
                .attr("id", "Value"+ questionNum + options[i])
                .html(options[i])
        ).append(
            // the hidden checkbox that will post the actual value
            $(document.createElement("input"))
                .attr("type", "checkbox")
                .addClass("hidden")
                .attr("id", "chkValue"+ questionNum + options[i])
                .attr("name", "value["+ questionNum +"][]")
                .attr("value", options[i])
        );
    }

    // create a new table row, append the "option and answer" cell
    // and question number cell, and append it to the table body
    $(document.createElement("tr"))
        .append(cell)
        .append($(document.createElement("td")).addClass("questionNum").html(questionNum))
        .appendTo("#tblQuestions tbody");
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="detailsBlock">
    <button id="btnAddQuestion">Add Question</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="details">
    <table id="tblQuestions">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Option and Answer</th>
                <th>Question No</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have set both the "SessionId" and "QuestionId" as primary keys so I have a composite key. You cant have the same question number in the same exam so thats why they are both primary keys

Comment: The problem is that how can I get the form to produce that data lol. That's what I am struggling with

Comment: @user1701484: I changed my answer. Take a look. Make sure you check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eg5QU/3/). To see what's going on with the checkboxes, just comment out the `display:none;` in the CSS for the `.hidden` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code generates this (note the bad name attribute):

```
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick(this, 1);" style="display:inline-block;" class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="value[answerF]" value="F" id="answerHRow">
```

Note that the name attribute is `value[answerF]` instead of the `value[1][]` as you wrote in your question.

Update your javascript and change the `$newBtn` line to:

```
    var $newBtn = $(("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this, " + gQuestionIndex + ");' />").replace('%s', $this.is(':visible') ? 'inline-block' : 'none')).attr('name', "value[" + gQuestionIndex + "][]").attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id') + 'Row');
```

Comment: Cheers for heads up on that :) problem is though that I am still getting same errors in php. Do you know what I need to change in php code?

Comment: What's the $_POST show now?  Also, you have way too many questions for this to be one question.  I'd suggest creating separate questions for your DB error and for your foreach error.

Comment: Ok, well for this question just concentrate on the foreach error. I will update the var_dump($_POST), give me 5 mins

Comment: I updated what the var_dump($_POST) is now showing in my question

Comment: Looks like you didn't update correctly?  Make sure you get the whole line above.

Comment: So that's updated now, what's the var_dump($_POST) show after the javascript is corrected??